Is trowel size 1/2" OK for 20mmx24"x36" outdoor porcelain tiles?
These are qualified as Large Format Tiles but on top of that they are also heavier so I am wondering if I need a bigger trowel
As per the manufacturer thinset mortar will be used. Not sure if the 100% coverage is critical here as the tiles will be used for pedestrian traffic (a porch) I see the point in having 100% tiles for thicker tiles which could crack if not supported from below, but these tiles in particular are designed to be also installed with not much under them


Is there someone to ask where you purchased them?

In the product literature you've attached, I don't see thinset mentioned at all. It shows being installed with pedestals. I found this: https://www.porceastone.com/blog/5-ways-to-install-outdoor-porcelain-tiles that mentions 5 different ways to install their tile, and none of them are using thinset.

search the doc for this: "Mortar: Mapei T / Keralastic, Mapei Granirapid (for fast setting), or Laticrete Multimax Lite. Dyna
Flex 600 Polymer Modified Thin Set Mortar

@MiniMe "mortar" doesn't appear at all on that web page. I'm not sure to which document you're referring.

https://assets-global.website-files.com/618971bf4ca1e7654ee39ec7/65c3fdf618b0568d166cc264_20240101%20-%20Porcea%20Stone%20Installation%20Guide.pdfhttps://assets-global.website-files.com/618971bf4ca1e7654ee39ec7/65c3fdf618b0568d166cc264_20240101%20-%20Porcea%20Stone%20Installation%20Guide.pdf

Where would the thinset go?    If it is on the ground it is only to adhere the pedestals.    If it is on the tile it would be the same thing but also seems like it would mess up the height.    I don't see thinset being used in the picture.    Honestly with the peg/hole system they have I am guessing no thinset is used (it would get in the way) if you are installing it on pedestals.
If you are not using pedestals and laying them on concrete for example 1/2" or whatever is fine because with something that large you should be back buttering it fully.    I would skim the back and use a 1/2" trowel.    (I am not a fan of using anything bigger than a 1/2" as it causes height issues in my experience.   I can skim a tile and use a 1/2" trowel uniformly.)

pedestal.  see this doc
https://assets-global.website-files.com/618971bf4ca1e7654ee39ec7/65c3fdf618b0568d166cc264_20240101%20-%20Porcea%20Stone%20Installation%20Guide.pdf

If they are strong enough to support weight when just on pedestals, I would think that a 1/2 inch trowel and thinset would work nicely.
I would still use a tile leveling system.

yeah that is the plan. However it is a challenge to find 20mm compatible leveling clips
